# Sending a data from php to js using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
    $users = [
            ['name'=>'alamin', 'password'=>'123', 'email'=>'alamin2aiub.edu'],
            ['name'=>'alamin', 'password'=>'123', 'email'=>'alamin2aiub.edu'],
            ['name'=>'alamin', 'password'=>'123', 'email'=>'alamin2aiub.edu']
        ];
```

Suppose I have these information in a php file. I want to sent this information to a external js file Is is possible using json? How can I do that? If someone can help me with the js it will really be helpful. TIA.

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Php echoes some data. If you want to get that data, you have to make a http request to the relevant place. If you want to do that from javascript, you can use ajax

Comment: Wrap the `json_encode` with a `file_put_contents` and save it to whatever file you want: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

based on your question details, its seems you trying to use data from php variable inside js file as follows:

Php code:

```
 <?php 
  $accNum = array("a","b","c"); //$accNum = $_REQUEST['accNum']; //you can you use your own value
 ?>
```

Script to assign php variable into javascript variable:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var accNumVar = <?php echo json_encode($accNum) ?>;
 </script>
```

Now you can use **accNumVar**  from your JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

example code inside **test.js** file

```
 console.log(accNumVar);
```

let me know if that example sorts out your issue. thanks